# Цепочка запросов с помощью RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rest, retrofit, rxjava

Мне нужно отправить два запроса POST на сервер. Второй запрос должен быть отправлен только после того как в него "будет вставлен" ответ от первого запроса. В документации вычитал, что для этого нужно использовать flatMap из RxJava. Первый запрос я переписал под RxJava а вот куда вставить flatMap и второй запрос не могу понять.
Как все выглядело изначально:

```
fun uploadNewImageAndContact(toPath: String?, newContactApi: ContactsApi) {
        val file = File(toPath)
        val fileReqBody: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val part: MultipartBody.Part =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.name, fileReqBody)

        // First Request
        imagesService.postImage(part).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                if (response.code() == 201) {
                    // Get Image response Id
                    val gson = Gson()
                    val imageResponse =
                        gson.fromJson(response.body()?.string(), ImageResponse::class.java)
                    imageMediaId = imageResponse.ids[0]

                    // Second Request
                    contactsService.postNewContact(newContactApi)
                        .enqueue(object : Callback<ContactsApi> {
                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ContactsApi>, t: Throwable) {

                            }

                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ContactsApi>, response: Response<ContactsApi>) {

                            }

                        })
                }
            }

        })

    }
```

Переписанный первый запрос:

```
  val disposable = CompositeDisposable()
        disposable.add(imagesService.postImage(part)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                    if (response.code() == 201) {
                        val gson = Gson()
                        val imageResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body()?.string(), ImageResponse::class.java)
                        imageMediaId = imageResponse.ids[0]
                    }
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

                }

            }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Должно получиться что-то вроде такого (в вашем случае):

```
val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

disposable.add(imagesService.postImage(part))
    .flatMap { 
        if (response.code() == 201) {
            val gson = Gson()
            val imageResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body()?.string(), ImageResponse::class.java)
            imageMediaId = imageResponse.ids[0]
            someService.someMethod(imageMediaId)
        } else { Single.error(Exception()) }
     }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
        override fun onSuccess(response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            //тут ответ второго запроса
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

        }

    }))
```

Но по хорошему надо бы, чтобы `imagesService.postImage(part)` выдавал уже `ImageResponse` - тогда `flatMap` сократится до одной строки:

> .flatMap { someService.someMethod(it.ids[0]) }

Answer (score 0):

У меня вообще возникает желание сделать последовательность запросов через fromCallable. Запросы сами по себе должны быть синхронными, сам callable выполнится в IO потоке и вернет data2, затем сразу onComplete. делать flatMap вижу смысл только если результат первого запроса может получать еще кто-то, кроме второго запроса

```
Observable.fromCallable{
    val data = API.firstRequest()
    val data2 = API.secondRequest(data)
    data2
}.subscribeOn(Scheldulers.io())
```